# Session value not working when FPC cache enabled

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Session value not working in blocks when FPC cache enabled.How to handle the session value in cache enabled blocks.I have added the customer session id as below.How to get the customer id from cache in a block.

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo() {
    $info = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
    $info['current_product_id'] = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    $info['customer_id'] = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    return $info;
}
```

Comment: What version Magento and what module you are using for PFC?

Comment: magento 1.4 and implemented the FPC in custom module

Comment: Well, maybe it is in the Custom module? But we need more for that.

Comment: Its the default magento block cache.Implemented from here.http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-block-caching/

Comment: @Ronn0 - Please check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to return a custom value from the `getCacheKey` method, for example:

```
public function getCacheKey(){
    if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId() == '') {
        return 'custom_cache_key_not_loggedin';
    } else {
        return 'custom_cache_key_' . Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    }
}
```

But please keep in mind this will not have any effect if your FPC (FULL page cache) is enabled. Because FULL page cache is not what you're asking for with your question.

**What should I do if i where you?**

What I would prefer in your situation is to skip caching specific (user) blocks when a user is loggedin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need to get the customer session id in another function getOptionHML()

Comment: Well, if you read it the right way you'll see that your way of implementing cachinig is not right. So it doesn't matter whére you need the value. It's a matter of improve your way of caching and your logic behind that.